# Regular Expression for Integer Range of 2-255

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a RegEx (for Javascript) for the numeric range of 2-255 and I'm having difficulty modifying similar RegExes to this purpose.

```
^([2-9]|1[0-6])$
```

That is 2-16 but I can't quite get the third digit correctly.

Comment: Are you sure that you need regex for this ?

Comment: @BelminBedak It's one of many patterns I'm testing for in an Angular application, so I would like to keep this pattern along with all the others to stay consistent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`^([2-9]|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$`

This matches 2-9, 10-99, 100-199, 200-249, and 250-255.

Comment: It needs to include 255 so I changed that last digit from a 4 to a 5 and it's perfect - thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

The solution using `RegExp.prototype.test()` function:

```js
var pattern = /^([2-9]|\d{2}|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|2[0-5][0-5])$/;
    
console.log(pattern.test(3));
console.log(pattern.test(300));
console.log(pattern.test(123));
console.log(pattern.test(255));
console.log(pattern.test(10));
console.log(pattern.test(256));
console.log(pattern.test(1));
console.log(pattern.test(199));
console.log(pattern.test(249));
```

However, there's some ***better*** approach for such case:

```js
var inRange = function (num) {
  var num = Number(num);
  return !isNaN(num) && (num % 1 === 0) && num >= 2 && num < 256;
};

console.log(inRange(254.4));
console.log(inRange(255));
```

Comment: `console.log(pattern.test(199));` => `false`

Comment: @EpicOrange, ok, fixed

Comment: `console.log(inRange(254.3))` => true (integer required)

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5, `254.3` - technically, it's in range

Comment: sure it is... but question is "integer 2-255" - 254.3 is not integer. it validates range but not number-type.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5, ok, missed the title. So be it. Fixed

Comment: I'm totally nitpicking here! But `console.log(pattern.test(249));` => `false`; `console.log(pattern.test("00"));` => `false`

Comment: @EpicOrange, that's great! so many attention to my answer. And ... fixed again. I'm curious, is it totally complete?

Answer (score 1):

```
^([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the shortest solutions **using RegExp** may be

```
 ^([2-9]\d?|1\d\d?|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))$
```

- `[2-9]\d?` - to match **2-9**, **20-99**
- `1\d\d?` - to match **10-19**, **100-199**
- `2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])` - to match **200-255**

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!  It's:

```
\b(?:2[0-4][0-9]{2}|25[0-5]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[2-9])\b
```

Comment: Many more elegant solutions here than what I came up with, thank you all!

Comment: it's shorter to use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`.